# HTML/CSS How to make a menu closed and then use class="active"

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I want to make a menu closed and when I visite a URL the `<li>` should change his class to class="active" but at the beginning I want to that class stay without class="active".

And I wonder which way is the best to do this Javascript or it can do it just with css.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var str=location.href.toLowerCase();
$(".navigation li a").each(function() {
if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
 $("li.active").removeClass("active");
$(this).parent().addClass("active");
}
 });
 })
```